# How to enable my terminal's ctrl + shift + c?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

I can't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> in my terminal since I set up something.

What can I do to get those shortcuts working again?

Comment: Don't you think that this _something_ you are talking about might be significant in helping you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Checkout **Keyboard shortcuts...** from **Edit** menu.

[image]

Comment: i edit it , but not useful .

Answer (score 0):

Do you use language selection with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> combination? It blocks the application from correctly detecting the combination, so the solution is to bind the language switching to the another combination (like <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>)